# Call to readHex value is not waiting for user input

Tags: assembly, x86

I am writing a program to prompt a user to enter a sentence, a hex value representing the number of characters to delete from the sentence, and a second hex value that represents the position to stare deleting from.  I am running into an issue prompting the user to enter the first hex value, for some reason this the assembler is not waiting for the user to input a value.  Prompting for a sentence is working (waiting for user) as is the last instruction to enter a hex value.  Why is this happening?

```
String1 BYTE "Enter a sentence: ", 0
String2 BYTE "Please enter the number of characters to delete(in 
hexidecimal): ", 0
String3 BYTE "Please enter to position from where to start deleting(in 
hexidecimal): ", 0
StringIn BYTE 50 DUP (?)
hexA WORD ?
hexB WORD ?

.code
main proc
call DeleteString

main endp

DeleteString PROC
mov edx, OFFSET String1
call WriteString
mov edx, OFFSET StringIn
call ReadString ;this instruction is waiting for user input
mov edx, OFFSET String2
call WriteString
call ReadHex ;this is my issue, it is being passed over by assembler
mov hexA, ax
mov al, 0Ah
call WriteChar
mov al, 0Dh
call WriteChar
mov edx, OFFSET String3
call WriteString
call ReadHex ;this instruction is waiting for user input
mov hexB, ax

DeleteString ENDP
end main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I needed to add my buffer size to ECX.  Works now!

```
mov edx, OFFSET String1
call WriteString
mov ecx, 50 ;######## THIS WAS MISSING ########
mov edx, OFFSET StringIn
call ReadString

mov edx, OFFSET String2
call WriteString
call ReadHex
mov hexA, eax
mov edx, OFFSET String3
call WriteString
call ReadHex
mov hexB, eax
```

Comment: is this Irvine32? You can... err... SHOULD always check the docs about the API, which you are calling. :)